# AES in JavaScript that matches PHP's mcrypt

Tags: php, javascript, cryptography, aes, mcrypt

Is there any JavaScript libs that lets you encrypt and decrypt 256 bit AES the way you do it with mcrypt in PHP (and get the same result of course)? I want to give it a variable-length message and a 32 chars key. All libs I find wants fixed-length blocks of cleartext and byte-arrays of keys.

This is how it's done in PHP:

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
echo mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "32 CHARS THAT REPRESENT MY KEY!!", "hello", MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

Comment: why would you want to encrypt using javascript? so that your encryption key could be seen by the world?

Comment: ah don't worry about that, key is sent through https.

Comment: HTTPS or not, the users can still see the key in your JavaScript. So if I for instance visited your site with a HTTPS connection, **I** could see still the encryption key by just viewing at the source or using a tool such as Firebug.

Comment: I know i know. But it doesn't matter if the user can see it as long as noone else can.

Comment: if you trust your user and the connection so much, why not letting HTTPS handle the security?

Comment: grr you guys stop bugging him about the reason. I need the same thing and its because I need to encrypt a message with a password on the client and decrypt it on the server WITHOUT TRANSMITTING THE KEY

Comment: People are "bugging" the OP because doing crypto in Javascript is fundamentally broken and a bad idea - because if you're not doing everything over HTTPS, an attacker can simply corrupt your JS to do what he wishes; or if you're using it to try and protect users against the site, the site can simply change the JS without notice.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! I made (the beginnings of) mcrypt for javascript. It doesn't have the exact same interface but it's similar. https://code.google.com/p/js-mcrypt/